# Py2neo Connection Refused Only with Cypher Execute

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo

I'm running py2neo 2.0.4 on a remote Neo4j 2.1.6 database. I'm able to connect to the database with some commands, but not with all.

Using the same connection uri for both instances:

This works fine.

```
test = self.graph_db.find_one('Node')
```

This does not.

```
test = self.graph_db.cypher.execute('MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 1')
```

Regardless of the actual contents of the query, I get the same connection refused results.

Comment: Can you update to include more of the code and the error+stacktrace you get when the second statement is executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of my service provider for Neo4j, we were able to determine the error and a fix.

This is a known flaw in pre-2.2 Neo4j. To resolve this error, use the py2neo rewrite function.

```
py2neo.rewrite(('http', '0.0.0.0', 7474, ('https', {host}, {port}))
```